# Uniform Convergence on a closed domain

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Suppose that {fn} is a sequence of continuous functions on the
>   interval [a, b] and that f is a continuous function on [a, b] such
>   that {fn} converges uniformly to f on (a, b). Prove that {fn}
>   converges uniformly to f on [a, b].

In other words, how can I demonstrate that {$f_n$} is also uniformly convergent at it's endpoints.

I know this Theorem: Suppose $f(x) = lim_{n→∞} f_n(x)$ for all $x ∈ [a,b]$, that each function $f_n$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and that the convergence is uniform. Then $\int_a^b f(x)dx = lim_{n→∞} \int_a^b f_n(x)dx$.

But this theorem refers to a closed domain. Additionally, I know that $\int_a^a f(x)dx = 0$. I'm unsure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: Uniform convergence cares about $\sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f_n(x) - f(x)|$, not $\int_a^b |f_n(x) - f(x)| \, dx$. How do we relate $\sup_{x \in (a,b)} |f_n(x) - f(x)|$ (which we're told goes to 0 as $n\to\infty$) to $\sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f_n(x) - f(x)|$ (which we want to prove goes to 0) as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: I'm trying to follow but I'm unsure how uniform convergence relates to supremums. There's almost no mention of it in my textbook.

Comment: Supremums are used in the definition of uniform convergence: the sequence $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly on the set $X$ iff for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N \implies \sup_{x \in X} |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \varepsilon$. In other words, this happens iff $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{x \in X} |f_n(x) - f(x)| = 0$.

Comment: Okay, so $sup_{x∈X} |fn(x)−f(x)| < ε$ for all $n≥N$ on the domain (a,b) as provided. But, I have no idea how to determine if this still applies at point a and point b.

Comment: We know that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0$ such that $n \geq N \implies \sup_{x \in (a,b)} |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$. Now $\sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f_n(x) - f(x)| = max\{ |f_n(a) - f(a)|, \sup_{x \in (a,b)} |f_n(x) - f(x)|, |f_n(b) - f(b)|\}$ and the functions are continuous...

Comment: *Hint*:  If $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $(a,b)$ to a function $f$, and if $f_n(a) \to f(a)$ and $f_n(b)\to b$ then  $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to   $f$.